# Not able to change icon in jquery

Tags: jquery

Please help I am new in Jquery

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#footerlist li a").on('click', function(event) {
        var link = this.href;
        var one =   link.split('#')[1];
    jQuery( "#"+one ).show();
  });
});
</script>
```

with this line:-

```
jQuery( "#"+one ).show();
```

I also want

```
jQuery('[href*="#"+one]').find("span").removeClass("fa fa-plus").addClass("fa fa-minus");
```

this condition to work but its not workin if works then it replace all + ixon to - i dont want that 
url is spliting from the above code 
Now I want from this Id on url that FAQ icon should be replaced from plus to minus
I have tried various code nothing work

Comment: Can you post an example anchor tag as well, so we can see how that's defined?

Comment: <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="" href="#ac_155_collapse5">

Comment: ```jQuery('[href*="#'+one+'"]')```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take care of quotes when you are trying to pass a variable:-

```
jQuery('[href*="#'+one+'"]').find("span").removeClass("fa fa-plus").addClass("fa fa-minus"); 
//------------------^Now it will be treated like a variable--------------
```

Comment: @eliana  glad to help you :):)

Comment: on click again i want to replace them back it always display - icon when its open or close

Comment: use toggleClass() concept

Comment: please explain how

Comment: Please ask a new question regarding that.For help  check documentation:- http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a local reference to the element you're selecting and simply use that again, to save searching the DOM repeatedly for the same thing.

Also, you don't need to remove the hash at the beginning of the href value, since you're using the value to find an element by ID...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#footerlist li a").on('click', function(event) {
        var $el = jQuery(this.href);
        $el.show();
        $el.find("span").removeClass("fa fa-plus").addClass("fa fa-minus"); 
    });
});
```